# System process disk activity

Tags: windows, background, disk-activity

I've detected some disk activity by 'System' process. Checked Windows Update and Task scheduler, nothing. Checked Event Viewer, only activity I can see is numerous journals being created in 'Security Audit'. From what I can tell, Windows is doing something, but I can't tell what exactly. What other options do I have to look for?

Comment: First, what is your total CPU usage over a period of about 10 minutes. Should average out at 5% or a bit less. Then open Admin Tools, Resource Monitor. Make sure the Disk line is open. Look up the PID to see if there is anything concerning. Disk is always busy, but not seriously so, on my machines. If CPU is as per above, there may be nothing to worry about.

Comment: the System process is the core of windows, so its not usually possible to get much insight on what its doing. you might look into tools like procmon.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.
@John CPU usage is 2-4%, in Resource Monitor it's 'System' process again. I have some understanding that disk always does some memory paging, this is illustrated by disk LED blinking once per second, but when it's blinking faster than that - something else must be going on. What's bothering me is that there are loads of events in Security Audit, accounts being logged on, privileges being assigned, etc
@ FrankThomas I'll check out procmon, maybe Process Explorer as well.

Comment: So CPU is normal.  You need to look at the tools which can report on Disk that we have suggested. That will let you see if Disk usage is normal or something unexpected is running.

Comment: LEDs are not a valid reflection of actual activity, simply its duration. most operations are faster than the human eye could see a LED change state in. blinking every second means only that during a given second there was at least a few MS of activity.